# Can we add events on react fragment?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

In my case, I have to wrap up the content in the parent component without adding extra div element to the DOM. So, I wrapped the element with the react fragment. I got a use case to add the native browser event to the react fragment, Is that even possible?

Comment: Yes, you can add events within your components in Fragments such as `onClick`. May I know what exactly do you need? Do add some code here so we know how to help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer, no, you can't add events on React Fragments. There is a detailed [discussion over here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12051), but as such, I don't think React Fragments will be supporting event handlers in the near future.

You may convert the your React Fragment (from `<> </>`) to a div element instead, and attach events to them.

```
return <div onClick={() => handleClick()}> </div>;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't add events on react fragment.

you can only add key only to react fragments like

```
<React.Fragment key={id}>
  .....
</React.Fragment>
```

not with this

```
 <key={id}>
  .....
 </>
```